# Is there a way to use load-mode for files in DrRacket?

Tags: scheme, racket, read-eval-print-loop

I would like to use DrRacket in the same way that it works for some of the ‘legacy languages’. In particular, I would like to go through a file as if it were a sequence of commands issued to the interpreter, and not as a module.

Essentially I want to run at least one file in load-mode, but I’m not sure if it’s possible to do it using DrRacket.

Ideally, I could:

*Specify a file that sets the language and maybe loads some modules, which runs by default at startup.

*Then load a file that is not a module (and has no #lang specification) and run it.

It’d also be nice (since I want to use Scheme) if it would allow redefinitions, just as the legacy languages do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, and in fact, the 'legacy languages' (and 'teaching languages') are actually just implemented as [DrRacket Plugins](http://docs.racket-lang.org/tools/index.html?q=drracket%20plugin). You can remove them from your copy of DrRacket and even add new ones.

There are various ways to do this depending on if you are okay with a `#lang` (or `#reader`) saved in the file. If you're not, its still doable, you just need to use [`drracket:get/extend:extend-unit-frame`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/tools/drracket_get_extend.html?q=drracket%3A#%28def._%28%28lib._drracket%2Ftool-lib..rkt%29._drracket~3aget%2Fextend~3aextend-unit-frame%29%29) to add your tool to DrRacket, and possibly [`drracket:get/extend:extend-definitions-text`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/tools/drracket_get_extend.html?q=drracket%3A#%28def._%28%28lib._drracket%2Ftool-lib..rkt%29._drracket~3aget%2Fextend~3aextend-definitions-text%29%29) to easily extend the definitions window.

I won't go into the details of making a generic DrRacket plugin here, that belongs in a different question...also the [DrRacket Plugins Manual](http://docs.racket-lang.org/tools/index.html?q=drracket%20plugin) has the information you need.<sup>1</sup> I will, however, point you in the direction of how you can use DrRacket in load mode out of the box.

Check out the [`racket/load`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/load-lang.html?q=racket%2Fload) language. It is designed to run each expression in the top level as if you were at a REPL typing it. I find it very useful for testing the differences between Racket module and top level interactions.

Of course, if you don't make a DrRacket plugin, you will still need to put:

```
#lang racket/load
```

at the top of your file, but you otherwise get a 'legacy mode' out of the box.

<sub><sup>1</sup>If it doesn't please continue to ask questions, and of course we always love help from anyone who is willing to contribute. <3</sub>